# Ubuntu-desktop removed after apt-get purge wine64

Tags: 18.04

I tried to remove wine using command `sudo apt-get purge wine64`.

But instead of removing wine , **all my app software were removed**.

When I restart Ubuntu it starts only in CLI mode. That means all the files required for GUI Ubuntu-desktop were also deleted.

When I try to reinstall using `sudo apt-get install Ubuntu- desktop`, it says

> unable to locate Ubuntu-desktop

Also I tried to install **lightdm** it says

> E:package lightdm has no installation candidate.

Is there any solution for this problem. Help me to reinstall Ubuntu-desktop and removed files if possible. Thank you

Comment: Try all in lowercase. Linux is case sensitive.

Comment: Seems like you have learned a valuable lesson: When apt warns you that it is about to remove a very, very large number of packages, don't immediately hit "Y". Read the output carefully instead.

Comment: You likely did something else. Removing wine64 would not remove anything but a couple of wine packages, removing those wine packages would not remove anything remotely like you've said.